# Logging from QueueHandler not appearing until future.result() is called

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I'm playing around with `logging.handlers.QueueHandler` (I'm trying to integrate it into my pytest suite).  Here's my MRE:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import logging
import logging.handlers
import multiprocessing
import threading

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger()

def init_job(log_queue):
    logging.getLogger().handlers = [logging.handlers.QueueHandler(log_queue)]

def func():
    logger.info('Here')

def thread_func(log_queue):
    while (record := log_queue.get()) is not None:
        logger.info('Handling record')
        logger.handle(record)

def main():
    log_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_func, args=(log_queue,))
    thread.start()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(initializer=init_job, initargs=(log_queue,)) as executor:
        future = executor.submit(func)
        future.result()
        log_queue.put(None)
        thread.join()
```

This works as expected.  However, I notice that the thread function doesn't receive the record until after `future.result()` is called.  That is, if I put `future.result()` after `thread.join()`, nothing gets logged.

How do I get my records in real time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without explicitly waiting for the submitted task to complete you have a race condition: Will the main process putting the sentinel value `None` on the queue to signal the log-handling thread to terminate occur before the submitted task has a chance to have a log message added to the queue? Probably not.

You only need to ensure that the `sentinel` value is put on the queue *after* all submitted tasks that put items on the queue (i.e. that log messages) have completed. That means executing the code that puts the sentinel after the termination of the `with` block, which implicitly calls `executor.shutdown(wait=True)` when exited to await the completion of all submitted tasks.

The following demonstrates that the log-handling thread is getting the messages immediately, i.e. before the submitted pool tasks complete:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import logging
import logging.handlers
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger()

def init_job(log_queue):
    logging.getLogger().handlers = [logging.handlers.QueueHandler(log_queue)]

def func():
    logger.info(f'Here sent at %f', time.time())
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f'func ended at', time.time())

def thread_func(log_queue):
    while (record := log_queue.get()) is not None:
        logger.handle(record)
        logger.info('Handled record received at %f', time.time())

def main():
    log_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_func, args=(log_queue,))
    thread.start()

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(initializer=init_job, initargs=(log_queue,)) as executor:
        executor.submit(func)
        time.sleep(1)
        executor.submit(func)
    # An implicit executor.shutdown(wait=True) is called here to wait
    # for all submitted tasks to complete.

    # Now it is safe to send sentinel:
    log_queue.put(None)
    thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
INFO:root:Here sent at 1693576570.512858
INFO:root:Handled record received at 1693576570.515859
INFO:root:Here sent at 1693576571.376398
INFO:root:Handled record received at 1693576571.377398
func ended at 1693576572.5241294
func ended at 1693576573.3787067
```

**Alternate, Simplified Approach**

Instead of creating your own log-handling thread, you can instead use a `logging.handlers.QueueListener` instance thread, which will handle putting the required sentinel on the queue when its `stop` method is called. Again, just be sure to call its `stop` method after all log messages have been generated:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import logging
import logging.handlers
import multiprocessing
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger()

def init_job(log_queue):
    logging.getLogger().handlers = [logging.handlers.QueueHandler(log_queue)]

def func():
    logger.info('Here sent at %f', time.time())
    time.sleep(2)
    logger.info('func ended at %f', time.time())

def main():
    log_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    # To output to sys.stderr:
    log_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    queue_listener = logging.handlers.QueueListener(log_queue, log_handler)
    queue_listener.start() # start thread

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(initializer=init_job, initargs=(log_queue,)) as executor:
        executor.submit(func)
        time.sleep(1)
        executor.submit(func)
    # An implicit executor.shutdown(wait=True) is called here to wait
    # for all submitted tasks to complete.

    # Stop thread:
    queue_listener.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
Here sent at 1693657780.574981
Here sent at 1693657781.438310
func ended at 1693657782.580926
func ended at 1693657783.445612
```